# Connecting to database server using php

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have written this piece of code to connect to MySQL server. However it does not seem to be work. Could someone enlighten me as to why this is the case?

```
    <?php
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "hostname"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
  echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

  $selected = mysql_select_db("asantec",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select asantec");

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books");

//fetch tha data from the database 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "tile:".$row{'title'}." author:".$row{'author'}."price: ". //display the results
   $row{'price'}."<br>";
}
//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

Comment: How does it "not work"? Errors? Unexpected output?

Comment: Note that `mysql_*` functions are depreciated in newer versions of PHP. You should use `mysqli_*` or `pdo_*`

Comment: which doesn't work `$dbhandle` or `$selected`?

Comment: You mean connect/select query isn't working?  or that $row{'title'} part?

Comment: it just outputs the data as i have written it which is so weird

Comment: ive done that and it still does the same thing

Comment: can you show us what's the output you are getting?

Comment: basically what ive typed as my code is what is being outputted instead of the data in the database

Comment: Nice database credentials. I would suggest deleting those from your code when posting on a public forum. I would also change your password on your remote database immediately.

Comment: if the php file is output as-is your server doesn't know it has to pipe the file through the php interpreter, probably due to either 1) you gave the file an extension that is not associated with php (.php and .phtml are commonly used extensions for php files) or 2) php isn't active on your server, check the server setup in that case.

Comment: OTOH, `echo "tile:".$row{'title'}.` should be `echo "tile:".$row['title'].` as $row is an array

Comment: @fvu : $row{'title'} will work, I think

Comment: @ViPin you're right, explained in [the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) under `Accessing array elements with **square bracket** syntax` of all places...

Answer (score 0):

This should be basically the mysqli version of what you wrote.

```
<?php
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $hostname = "creative.coventry.ac.uk";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, "asantec");

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM books;");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $author, $price); //Put all your expected variables here

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo $id.'<br />';
        echo $title.'<br />';
        echo $author.'<br />';
        echo $price.'<br /><br />';
    }

    $mysqli->close();
?>
```

Also, if you have any issues in the code you've posted, this will work. Check your DB credentials and the data you're querying.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me, I couldn't help but notice the Coventry University server being displayed on here which if I'm right to assume, you are a Coventry University student?

Do you have permission to be publishing and exposing such information about the university servers on here? This can lead to many security issues and can potentially cost the university a fortune to stop hackers infiltrating our databases.

Furthermore, you shouldn't be taking codes off of people on the internet if it is not stated as open source. This is an extremely serious case and you can very well be held accountable for level 3 plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

I too came across this, and due to the seriousness of the situation, even though I am no longer part of the Uni staff,  I've still gone out of my way to report this to the Coventry university Academic Conduct Officer, who happen to take these issues very seriously.

Chris, you seem like a bright student, and if I'm correct you should be in your third and final year now. It baffles me as to why you'd put everything at jeopardy just to gain some help which you should be academically capable of doing yourself.

All the best,

Mike Morgan

Comment: this seems not like an answer..
To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post..